# Call the specific position in list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am kinda new in Python, still learning. Can you guys help me how can I call specific position of list?

For example: **list_of_numbers = [24, 45, 743, 23, 541]:**

How can I get the number **743**?

Comment: Please attempt something before posting on SO

Comment: Try by your self first, just do it with brute force. No fancy trickery needed here :)

Comment: list_of_numbers[2]

Comment: Users should feel free to ask questions if they need help. They will learn faster with our help rather than blindly attempting to solve a problem that they might not even have the resources to solve. If you don't want to answer the question, you ignore it. Don't put down curious people looking to better themselves.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to index your list. Do this by naming the variable for the list and then putting the number it is along the list in square brackets remember Python starts counting from 0. For example:

```
    List_of_numbers=[24, 45, 753, 23, 541]
    List_of_numbers[2]
```